# Graphs lost after upgrading to Gitlab 6.0

Tags: gitlab

Yesterday I've upgraded my Gitlab installation from 5.3 to 6.0 (technically from 5.3 to 5.4 and 5.4 to 6.0), and I can't display Network and other Graphs since then.

On the network page it seems some Javascript is not loaded, as I got a 'Network is not defined' error. Graphs seems to be a different issue, but I can't find anything in the logs.

Is it a bug or I did something wrong?
Both functions were working fine before the upgrade.

Comment: I've created a brand new project to test this issue. The network tab is the same (Network is not defined JS error), but the graphs are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in GitLab. It breaks when it encounters a commit that doesn't change any files, such as when creating a branch.

It is in the issue tracker as [issue #4867](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4867) and has been fixed in `master`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to precompile your assets:

```
sudo service gitlab stop
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production 
sudo service gitlab start
```

Comment: This helped, the network function is working again.
The other half of the original question is still a problem, Graphs are not working still.
I can see two versions of the issue, the first variant is not displaying graphs at all, just the top line saying "Commits to master, excluding merge commits. Limited by 6,000 commits", and nothing under that. The second variant displays empty graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running

```
bundle exec rake cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production
```

as per https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4874

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately it did not solved the problem. :(