# GitLab broken UI after upgrade from 6.4 to 6.5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gitlab

Yesterday I've updated GitLab from 6.4.3 to 6.5.1 and ended up with broken UI (see screenshot https://www.evernote.com/shard/s4/sh/ca64f23a-ea3d-4ef9-bfb6-d6d7d2123ebe/d58835f794611fd3dd3c84397e7b5576)

I think it has probably something to do with new Bootstrap 3 responsive UI introduced in this version. Is it general problem of 6.5.1 or just my instance? As I noticed demo version http://demo.gitlab.com/ is stil running 6.5.0 and UI seems to be ok.

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Comment: Is it similar to https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6151?

Comment: probably yes symptoms seems to be very similar

Comment: Ok, I have added that reference as an answer for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OP kocour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3231386/kocour) concluded [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333794/gitlab-broken-ui-after-upgrade-from-6-4-to-6-5/21334464?noredirect=1#comment32166264_21334464), as in "[Graphs lost after upgrading to Gitlab 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18440397/6309)";

> my fault... I just forgot to precompile assest using:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production
```

---

Original answer:

Those issues are tracked by [issue 6151](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6151): "New layout/responsive Issues"

> UI in GitLab 6.5.1 doesn't look as polished as in 6.4.3, mostly because of the new version of bootstrap I guess.
>
> - Mobile view - project list is inaccessible ([issue 6114](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6114))
> - Padding in alert blocks is not nice, and the top block should be a warning block
> - Toggled menu on mobile is really ugly,

I suppose pull requests will soon amend and fix this situation.

Comment: ok, my fault... I just forgot to precompile assest using _sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production_

Comment: @kocour Ok. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Executing only

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production
```

not solving issue for me, solved after removing `<gitlab_home>/tmp/cache/assets` folder prior to execute the command.